# Using dropdown to populate text area fields

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm relatively new to front end development and I can't find an answer to what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a dropdown list in my html, populated by a list of String values which have came from a java rest endpoint using ng-repeat.

```
<select id='optionDisplay' name='templateOption'>
    <option ng-repeat="t in templates">{{ t }}</option>
</select>
```

(The list is populated by keys of a map, I now need the values of the map to get the information I need) eg

```
Map<String, Template> getAllTemplateMap = DBUtil.getInstance().getAllTemplateMap();

List<Template> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Template template : getAllTemplateMap.values()) {
        tempList.add(template);
    }
```

Now I have a few text areas below the drop down, and I would like these to be populated with values associated with the option selected from the dropdown, which would derive from the value (Template) of the map.

Eg fields come from the Template which has methods like .getName(), .getDescription() and so on.

Do I have to create a rest endpoint for each value? And how would I achieve this in the javascript controller to populate the text boxes??

Controller code -

```
app.controller('TempCtrl', function($scope, $http,$location) {

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/templatepanel/templates")
     .then(function(response) {
         $scope.templates = response.data;  
});


$http.get("http://localhost:8080/templatepanel/appname")
     .then(function(response) {
        $scope.appName = response.data;
});

console.log('getting template list');
});
```

And thanks for the downvotes, no need to be a douche to someone looking for direction.

Comment: Show your code where you are making a web service call (AngularJS code - client side) to the Java controller/ RestController (server side).

Comment: @MAC added the controller, the top function gets the list, second function doesn't do anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of how it can be done.Here `$scope.optionList` is your value from middle layer which you can get through a http request.

Then use `select` & `ng-options` to build the select box & add a function to `ng-change`. So on change of value from `select`(drop down in your case) the function associated with `ng-change` will be called.

In this function update the model of the input box with the selected value.

```js
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('TestController', ['$scope', function($scope) {


  $scope.optionList = [{
    value: 'value1',
    name: 'name1'
  }, {
    value: 'value2',
    name: 'name2'
  }]
  $scope.updateTextBox = function(val) {
    $scope.inputField = $scope.unit

  }


}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="unit" ng-options="opt.value as opt.name for opt in optionList track by opt.value" ng-change="updateTextBox()">
        </select>

    <input ng-model="inputField"> </div>


</div>
```